# [moveit_simple_controller_manager] Longer controller action timeout

Tags: ros, moveit, move-group

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running MoveIt and Gazebo using a single launch file. Because my computer's slow, sometimes Gazebo takes quite a while to start, so I had to increase the timeout on my controller_manager spawner. Unfortunately, move_group / moveit_simple_controller_manager are quite impatient and throw the error  "Action client not connected: /position_trajectory_controller/follow_joint_trajectory." Looking into the code, it looks like ActionBasedControllerHandle is hardcoded to wait 15 seconds and then give up (3 tries with 5 seconds in between).

Besides splitting up the launch file, is there a way to have the moveit_simple_controller_manager wait longer (or indefinitely) for the controllers? Or maybe some way to have move_group wait for a trigger before it tries to create the controller manager? Or a way to retrigger creating FollowJointTrajectoryControllerHandle after it has failed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250612/%5Bmoveit_simple_controller_manager%5D-longer-controller-action-timeout/) by [mrjogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1576/mrjogo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2016-12-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could open a PR that makes that 15 seconds a parameter configurable from roslaunch / yaml

---

Originally posted by [Dave Coleman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1279/dave-coleman/) with karma: 1396 on 2016-12-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2016-12-24**:
A pull-request that adds a ros parameter to make `move_group` wait *indefinitely* for the clients would be appreciated a lot!
I noticed this too and find it quite an awkward behavior!